# How to transform a partial differential equation(PDE) into another

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have the following PDE:
$$ω_t +d(1-\frac{2ω}{b})ω_x=0 \quad x\in \mathbb{R},\quad t>0$$
where $ω=ω(x,t)$ and $b,c:constants$ and $c>0$

And I want to transform it into :$$y_T+(1-2y)y_x=0 \quad x\in \mathbb{R},\quad T>0$$
where $y=y(x,T)$. I know that I have to transform the variable $t$ but I can't manage doing it.

Any ideas please?

Comment: Do you know anything about nondimensionalization?

Comment: Ian@Idon't know .Could you help me please?I would be gratefyl if i had any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of scale-only change of variable process either is or is closely related to nondimensionalization. (I must point out that it is weird that you aren't scaling in $x$). The basic procedure is to scale every unit in the problem independently. I would assume from context that $\omega$ has its own units separate from $t$ and $x$ (if it is already dimensionless then this situation is even more weird).

So you take $t=t_C T,\omega=\omega_C y$, and plug that in to get

$$\frac{\omega_C}{t_C} y_T + d \left ( 1 - \frac{2\omega_C}{b} y \right ) \omega_C y_x = 0.$$

Then you choose values of $\omega_C$ and $t_C$ (depending on the other parameters, and consistent with the dimensions that they need to have) to achieve a desired simplification. So here $\omega_C$ and $t_C$ depend on $b$ and $d$ in a fairly simple way.

Comment: Ian@,thank you!

Comment: @george_ioanidis If you are happy with Ian's answer, perhaps accept it so that a) it recognises you appreciate Ian's effort and b) it tells the system that the question has been answered.

Comment: mattos@do you mean that the above Ian's approach is not correct?Do you have a different idea about it?

Comment: @george_ioanidis No, mattos is suggesting you click the checkbox next to my answer to accept it, provided that it answered your question. This gives me reputation (which is another way to show appreciation in addition to the comment) and also removes the question from the unanswered queue.